# Icons To be Used In Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on an API based application for Windows 8. I have a slight confusion.
I'm making images to be used in the tiles. I've made some using this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

Now when I open the project and check Assets/Icons Folder, I observed different sizes which were as follows:

```
FlipCycleTileLarge    691 * 336
FlipCycleTileMedium   336 * 336
FlipCycleTileSmall    159 * 159
IconicTileMediumLarge 134 * 202
IconicTileSmall       71  * 110
```

Can anyone tell me the exact number of images and their resolutions with their corresponding names which are to be put in the folder so the app is not rejected.

Note: My app doesn't provide anything like Live Tiles.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to read the [App Submission Requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Section 4.7 gives you the list of images that are required. Read the full section for all the details but at a high level you will need:

- App list image

  - For Windows Phone OS 7.1 , a 62 x 62 pixel PNG image.
  - For Windows Phone 8 , a 99 x 99 pixel PNG image.
- Default Tile images

  - For Windows Phone OS 7.1 , a PNG image for the medium Tile size. For more information about the image dimensions, see Windows Phone OS 7.1 Tile template.
  - For Windows Phone 8 , a PNG or JPEG image for the medium and small Tile sizes. The image dimensions depend on the Tile template you've chosen for your default Tile. For more information about the dimensions of the images, see the corresponding Tile template topic: Flip Tile template for Windows Phone 8, Iconic Tile template for Windows Phone 8, or Cycle Tile template for Windows Phone 8.
- Windows Phone Store app image

  - A 300 x 300 pixel, non-transparent PNG image.

More details on the [tile images are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: You are always to my rescue. Ok see, my app doesnt have any live tile feature. I just want to display my app name on my tiles. Thats it . what I should use

Comment: FlipCycleTileLarge ,FlipCycleTileMedium,FlipCycleTileSmall  these are the three I have put in my Assets/Icons folder but there are two more images present (IconicTileMediumLarge,IconicTileSmall) what do do with them ? can I delete them?

Comment: Sure you can delete them. Make sure you reference the right ones in your app manifest.

Comment: Hi, i have used the three images stated above, can you please tell me what to write in the AppManifest File ? for these three images and one last thing, do we need Small , Medium as well as Large tile? and ApplicationIcon should be of 100*100 or 99*99 as the default one in the project was 100*100

Comment: Ok so i found something. WPAppManifest.xml Shows me this (Tile Template:TemplateFlip) Shows TileImages (Small,Medium) is that fine ?

Comment: actually I did it :) thanx Man

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes across this post and has the issue I had where XAP packaging failed and that VS2012 can not find the file then check for spaces in the file name.  I had the issue where my tiles were "tilename 99.png" and it keep giving me the XAP packaging failed message.  So I finally changed the file name to "tilename_99.png" and it worked.

Hope this helps someone in the same predicament.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best MSDN page describing application icon sizes, tile sizes and all aspects for scaling factors and pixel density for Windows RT (Universal Apps) for Win 8.1, if you are still going to update your app:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781198.aspx