# Application Icon and Tile sizes for apps which works on windows phone 7.1, WP7.8 and WP8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.8, application-icon

I'm jus so confused about application icon sizes that need to be used for WP. My app works on all the three, 7.1 , 7.8 and 8.0. I use Windows Phone 8 SDK.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031762/icons-to-be-used-in-windows-phone-8) gives the sizes need. My question is in the WMAppManifest.xml file, since my app supports all the three, for the App icon which one do we give? the 66x66 or the 99x99. Similarly for Tile which one do I need to give? Is the app icon same as app list icon.

When I create a new WP8 project, the ApplicationIcon is of size 100x100? when the size mentioned is 99x99.

Which is the default tile size that i need to give for the app to work in both all 3 versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app targets Phone 7.1 (which can be used on 7.1, 7.8 and 8) then all you need is are the normal icons (ApplicationIcon.png and Background.png). If you want to support the new tiles in 7.8 and 8 check out [this blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/22/windows-phone-7-8-and-windows-phone-8-live-tile-light-up-for-windows-phone-os-7-1-apps.aspx) from the Windows Phone dev team. Also an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and a [handy helper](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/).

Comment: ApplicationIcon.png and Background.png should be of what size? its 100x100 for WP8 and 66x66 for WP7.1

Comment: Use the defaults for WP7. 173x173 for Background and 62x62 for ApplicationIcon. They will be scaled for you for the other devices